# PyOpenGl runtime error after cx_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyopengl

I'm trying to compile a shader running PyOpenGL and PyOpenGL_Accellerate v 3.1.2 from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Runs fine, but after cx_freezeing it I get: "no array-type handler for type  when calling glShaderSource

I have tried a suggestion to force include OpenGL.arrays.ctypesparameters into cx_Freeze build but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Had to force add OpenGL.arrays to the cx_freeze setup.

```
options = {"build_exe": {
        "packages": ["OpenGL.arrays"]
        }
```